# I am trying to run my AVD emulator and why is this happening

Tags: android

Does not pop up the emulator. however, I see the following error message instead.

[2011-11-10 21:03:19 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe.

[2011-11-10 21:03:19 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.

[2011-11-10 21:03:19 - Emulator] please use -help for more information

Thanks StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've installed the android sdk into your Program Files folder. You should install it into a path with no spaces, `C:\android-sdk` or something.

To break it down, it's calling the executable without quotes around the path to the file, i.e. `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe` is viewed without quotes as calling the program `C:\Program` with the parameter of `Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe`. It's a simple flaw that they haven't fixed in several versions. It's especially problematic sense the installer naturally wants to install in Program Files by default.